# How to associate an operator with a priority value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, postfix-notation

I want to implement Dijkstra's Shunting-yard algorithm for the [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). In order to do that, I have to implement a table which stores priority for operators, as such:

| operator | priority |
| --- | --- |
| ( | 0 |
| +, - | 1 |
| *, / | 2 |

How do I do that?

Comment: IMHO [`std::unordered_map<char, int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to compare like `priority['('] < priority['+']`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik would you mind elaborating a bit, please? I'd like to learn something new :)

Comment: Depends how you'll need to access the priorities. Definitely not a priority queue, though, unless you want to rebuild heaps constantly

Comment: @Jeffrey check my edit

Comment: I don't see the connection with Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @trincot https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: You wrote _"the Dijkstra's algorithm"_. This is [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Shunting yard is one of Dijkstra's algorithms but it's not **the** Dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: I don't understand why the question got closed, really. To me it is a legit question, I want to understand the best way to implement this behavior.

Comment: Shunting Yard algorithm is indeed related to your question, and that has nothing to do with Dijkstra"s algorithm, right?

Comment: @trincot "The algorithm was invented by Edsger Dijkstra" - that's why I've said "Dijkstra's algorithm for the reverse polish notation".

Comment: OK, but that is not how it is referred to. Dijkstra's algorithm is commonly referring to shortest path finding.

Comment: While Dijkstra did invent the shunting-yard algorithm, "Dijkstra's algorithm" is the established name for an algorithm for finding shortest paths in a graph. That is, they are both Dijkstra's algorithms, but only one of them is "Dijkstra's algorithm".

Comment: Do you see my first comment? I started with _"IMHO"_ (In My Humble Opinion) to focus the problem. Your question is opinion-based

Comment: @ThomasSablik What would be the difference between std::unordered_map vs this get_priority that was recommended to me?

Comment: You should read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_ What have you found out in your research for `std::unordered_map` and lookup tables?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I will look into them myself then. Thanks

Comment: you should read up on the difference between a static and a dynamic problem. the answer by @Ayxan Haqverdili is perfect in all regards and there is no better or simpler solution. if people hadn't been faster than me, i would have answered the same and added a close vote too -- stackoverflow isn't a place for discussion of student homework, there are many forums for that. 
and i can only second what others said: dijkstras algorithm is for pathfinding :)

Comment: One of the nice things about RPN (or PN) is that they obviate the need for operator priority.  Adding operator priority seems odd to me.

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you attempting to build a priority queue for reverse Polish notation? The priority is hardwired into the order in which the tokens are placed. Who told you you need a priority queue?

Comment: Removing Dijkstra threw the baby out with the bathwater. "Dijkstra's algorithm for RPN" was never incorrect or even ambiguous in the first place, and removing it changed the topic from parsing to evaluation, and lost the motivation for the precedence table, which is part of this algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a fixed-number of key-value pairs that are known at compile time, you don't need the dynamic nature and overhead of `std::unordered_map`. You can use a simple switch statement, which is static and harder to get wrong:

```
int get_priority(char const op) {
  switch (op) {
    case '(':
      return 0;
    case '+':
    case '-':
      return 1;
    case '*':
    case '/':
      return 2;
    default:
      return -1; // handle the error
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks good to me. Would you mind explaining why this would be a better answer than, for example, an std::unordered_map?

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu I've tried to add some explanation. Basically, it's a static and simpler/more restricted lookup table that's also easier to use.